# why whereIn() is better than relations in laravel?

Tags: php, laravel, database, eloquent, laravel-9

Database of our laravel application is increasing and queries time is also increasing. One thing I have noticed about queries is `whereIn()` is way faster than `relations` call
for Example

I need to get all consignments of customer so with laravel relation what i will do

```
$customers = Customer::with('consignments')->where('id','>',1)->get();
//and now i can access all consignments
foreach($customers as $customer ){
$customer->consignments
}
```

But this is very slow even when I am using indexes. (Maybe I am not using indexes properly)

on the other hand if I use `whereIn()` it is way faster

```
$customer_ids = Customer::selct('id')->where('id','>',1)->pluck('id')->toArray();
$consignments = Consignment::whereIn('customer_id',$customer_ids)->get()
```

This is very fast. Am I making any mistake here?

Can we make laravel relations fast?

Comment: Install Laravel debugbar so that you can get to grips with the number of queries, the number of hydrated models and particularly, the amount of memory in use.  Do you really have a use case where you need all customers and all consignments in memory at once?

Comment: those 2 examples are doing different things as well, the first is getting all customer records (all fields) the second is only getting the ids ... if you don't need the customer records you can do the relationship from the other direction as well with a `whereHas` to only get consignment records ... though not saying that it would be quicker/more efficient

Answer (score 0):

You are mainly comparing eager loading vs lazy loading.

In your first example, you are using eager loading. You are basically bringing everything at once. You execute one single query against your database.

In your second example, you are using lazy loading. First, you are bringing the user's information. Second, you are bringing the related consignments. You execute two different queries against your database.

Response times depend on different factors.

- Database data size
- Database structure such as data types and indexes
- Database server resources such as CPU and memory
- Response size
- Network bandwidth

For example, if your resources of CPU and memory are limited, your database server might be having a difficult time trying to process the eager loading approach where you have one single but complex query.

You can get the raw query using the `toSql()` method. You can then execute these queries directly in your database and use a query execution plan to detect which query suits better for your use case.